# How to calculate the signal-to-noise ratio for an image?

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I've started with a “perfect” image 'without noise'.

Then I added some noise to it. I've used gaussian white noise for this purpose.

```
In = In+0.5*randn(size(Io))
```

The combined image (my “noisy image”) has a signal to noise ratio with some meaning because I can compare it to the perfect image.

My question is how can I calculate the 'SNR Value'.

Answer (score 1):

A standard metric to measure noise in an image is the peak signal to noise ratio, PSNR.
The formula for this metric:

[image: PSNR]

See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)  for more details.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not asking about the PSNR i ask how we calculate the SNR